# Changing OMP_SCHEDULE leads to incorrect results

Tags: fortran, openmp, race-condition, schedule

I wrote a Smoothed Particle Hydrodynamics code that produces correct results when using a static schedule for OpenMP. When I say correct results, I mean that I have validated them against analytical solutions.

However, I wanted to switch to a dynamic schedule since the work to be done for each iteration is not constant. As far as I understand, in that case, a dynamic schedule leads to a faster computation. Indeed, it runs faster but the results are now incorrect, leading to what appears to be IMO a race condition.

[image]

A simplified version of the loops I applied OpenMP to is as follows :

```
array1 = 0.0 ! Array of size N
array2 = 0.0 ! Array of size N
array3 = something ! Array of size N, will not change through the loop
!$OMP PARALLEL DO SHARED(array1, array2, array3) FIRSTPRIVATE(N) PRIVATE(i, j, N2, temp) SCHEDULE(runtime) DEFAULT(none)
do i=1,N

    N2 = function1(i) ! Reading from array3 and some math

    do j=1,N2

        temp = 0.0

        temp = function2(i,j) ! No writing here, just reading stuff from array3, doing math and storing the result in temp

        array1(i) = array1(i) + temp
    end do

    array2(i) = function3(array1(i)) ! Some math on array1(i), just reading

end do
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

I looked into the "false sharing" problem, but it seems to be only a performance issue meaning that it does not affect the results (if I am correct).

Did somebody already faced a problem like that? Am I missing a race condition?

Comment: Smoothed Particle Hydrodynamics

Comment: Can you  provide an example we can compile and run and see the wrong result? How should the results look like? See How to Make a [mcve].

Comment: Where are those functions? What do they do? Please show the complete code.

Comment: I'll try to make a minimal working example. Concerning the results  : https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nCxd.jpg0

Comment: Well the image is nice, but does not help much unless we know how to plot it. We need numbers.

Comment: Make sure you haven't accidentally turned a local variable in one or more of the functions you call from within the parallel loop into a static (`save`'d) variable by initialising it at the point of declaration, e.g. `integer :: var = 5`.

Comment: My advice is to start with a small problem size, get your results from a single-threaded execution, and then increase the number of threads you use step by step. I think the example you provide is not enough, since there are some details hidden, even though you point out that they are read-only.